# Virtualbox bridged network adapter with multiple host network interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I have an unusual networking situation.

**Network**

There are two networks. One is the tethering interface from my phone. The other is for LAN purposes only so there is no internet access.

The two networks are a necessity because LAN functionality of my phone's network is quite poor. Additionally, I carry it with me so it would cause the host machine to be frequently offline.

**Host Machine (running Windows 10 Pro)**

The host machine is configured to connect to the LAN network and the phone's tethering network simultaneously. The LAN interface is via ethernet. The phone's hotspot tethering interface is through a USB wireless adapter.

**Virtual Machine (Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.3 LTS)**

For the purpose of the VM, I need it to access the host's network for LAN purposes. However, I also need the VM to access the internet at certain instances through my phone's tethering hotspot. I have tried configuring the VM to use a Bridged Network Adapter. However, the VM doesn't connect to anything upon enabling it! It seems it will only connect to one network. How can I configure the Virtual Machine to access the host's wireless and ethernet interfaces simultaneously?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing, it appears the virtual machine has access to the LAN network with a NAT network adapter! I would hazard to guess Virtual Box combined both of the host's network interfaces into one before passing down through the chain to the Virtual Machine. I have yet to conduct testing to determine what will happen when my phone's tethering is off.

The conclusion above was determined on the evident factors below:

- My Virtual Machine has internet access (must be phone's tether)
- Though the Virtual Machine's (Ubuntu Desktop) network file browser didn't detect any LAN servers, I was able to detect the host's LAN server file system by connecting to the server directly (smb://device-name).

**UPDATE:**

It is confirmed, LAN continues to work after disabling the phone's tethering. It works seamlessly! Enabling tethering, the computer automatically reconnects and the VM regains connectivity without ever losing LAN!